# VS could not load file or assembly Slimdx

Tags: c#, dll, directx

i just downloaded **SlimDx** library from [here](https://github.com/SlimDX/slimdx)

and  when i simply add a refernce it to `Slimdx.dll` it works fine, however when i run the program it fails on the creation of  the surface:

```
 public Device device;
   
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface surface = device.GetRenderTarget(0))
        {
            
        }

    }
```

it just throws an error :

> Could not load file or assembly SlimDX, Version=2.0.13.43, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1b0c32fd1ffe4f9'

I have no idea what im doing wrong.. so i would thank you very much if someone could light my eyes..

Comment: Did you try to move the DLL across the binary ?
Did you try to check the platform ? (x86 - x64) ?

Comment: @MickaelThumerel i used x64 one.

Comment: Have you installed SlimDX (so it is present in the GAC) or have you checked "copy to output" for the reference?